# Is there a RESTful API for pubishing RAMl to anypoint platform?

Tags: mule

We would like to keep our RAML and Schema files in local source control for tracking of changes.  Is there a wat to publish an updated RAML file and any associates Schema/JSON examples to the Anypoint Platform via an API or FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do this with MuleSoft's Anypoint Platform API, documentation available here: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/anypoint-platform/#/portals/organizations/68ef9520-24e9-4cf2-b2f5-620025690913/apis/11197/versions/11566/pages/11183

You can also follow this thread on the MuleSoft forums for more information: http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/35618/is-there-a-restful-api-to-publish-updated-ramlsche.html

Hope that helps,
Mike